# Finding $l$ such that the Legendre differential equation has a polynomial solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, legendre-polynomials

I was given this problem for practice and was wondering if my approach was correct:
$$
(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + 3ly = 0. 
$$

At first I thought of just using $l = 2$ since the Legendre DE is defined in that way (with the $l(l+1)y$ term). But I settled on first using the power series method to solve for the recurrence and then see if I could find $l$, but I'm completely stuck after that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the power series approach is the right one. If we assume that
$$
y=\sum_{n=0}^ma_nx^n
$$
with $a_m\neq0$, using the ODE yields
$$
0=(1-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^mn(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-2x\sum_{n=0}^ma_nnx^{n-1}+3l\sum_{n=0}^ma_nnx^{n}\\
\Leftrightarrow 0=\sum_{n=0}^{m-2} \Big( (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - n(n-1)a_n -2na_n+3la_n \Big)x^n+ \Big( - (m-1)(m-2) -2(m-1)+3l \Big)a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \Big( - m(m-1) -2m+3l \Big)a_mx^m\\
\Leftrightarrow 0=\sum_{n=0}^{m-2} \Big( (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - n(n+1)a_n+3la_n \Big)x^n+ \Big( - (m-1)m +3l \Big)a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \Big( - m(m+1) +3l \Big)a_mx^m\\
$$
Since $a_m\neq0$, that means that $l=\frac{m(m+1)}{3}$ and $a_{m-1}=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I talked about it with my professor earlier and he told me that both approaches were correct but the one where we say l = 2 is much easier since we can just say we get the Legendre polynomial of order 2 as a polynomial solution and that would be enough.